# azure create function for ADFv2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I'd like to create an Azure function that is triggered by ADFv2.  I've found all sorts of information about pointing the ADFv2 Function widget to your existing Azure Function, but I'm struggling with how this function is triggered.  My functions are currently triggered via a timer.  I've also seen references that the return value needs to be JSON but currently my trigger returns System.Threading.Tasks.Task.  My function is written in C#.

I currently plan to get all the values from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable, but would like to know how to pull values passed from ADFv2 also.

What type of trigger do I create a my C# trigger with to use with ADFv2?  What return value do I need to define?  And if anything other than Task, how do I do that?  Finally how to I read parameters passed from ADFv2?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Function activity allows you to run Azure Functions in a Data Factory pipeline. To run an Azure Function, you need to create a linked service connection and an activity that specifies the Azure Function that you plan to execute.

[image]

The return type of the Azure function has to be a valid JObject. (Keep in mind that JArray is not a JObject.) Any return type other than JObject fails and raises the user error Response Content is not a valid JObject. It's a restriction from Data Factory side.

I don't think , there is any restriction on the trigger side, you can use any of the triggers you have, from the output side, object should be of type JObject.

Additional Reference:

https://visualbi.com/blogs/microsoft/azure/execute-azure-functions-azure-data-factory/

for the passing parameter, here is how you can achieve that:

[image]

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/

Hope it helps.